# object become inflated in render

Tags: rendering, cloth-simulation

absolute newbie here.

I am following a youtube tutorial on how to make a couch (blender guru).

Everything seems fine in solid and material view but in render parts of the couch that use the pink fabric material become inflated. Where should I look to resolve this? Any idea on what could be causing it?

[[image: Material view]
[image: render view]
[image: Nodes in case it's relevant]

Comment: It's your displacement node

Comment: Yees, I figured it out! thank you!